# MongoDB: find subdocument instances with similar date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection with a structure like

```
[
  {
    name: "name1",
    instances: [{value:1, score:2, date:<ISODate>},
                {value:2, score:5, date:<ISODate>},
                {value:2.5, score:9, date:<ISODate>},
                ...]
  },
  {
    name: "name2",
    instances: [{value:6, score:3, date:<ISODate>},
                {value:1, score:6, date:<ISODate>},
                {value:3.7, score:5.2, date:<ISODate>},
                ...]
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to find if there are two (or more) instances of the same `name` where the instance's dates are from the same day, and return those instances.

Later on I would like to delete all but one of those instances, but as a start I want to be able to find them.

I tried aggregation and grouping by date, but couldn't figure out how to compare only the day (not the entire date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have the following test documents inserted in the test collection for demonstration purposes:

```
db.test.insert([
{
    "name" : "name1",
    "instances" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 1,
            "score" : 2,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 2,
            "score" : 5,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 2.5,
            "score" : 9,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "name2",
    "instances" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 6,
            "score" : 3,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 1,
            "score" : 6,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 3.7,
            "score" : 5.2,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-02-04T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name" : "name1",
    "instances" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 6,
            "score" : 3,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-03-05T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 1,
            "score" : 6,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : 3.7,
            "score" : 5.2,
            "date" : ISODate("2015-02-04T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
])
```

then the following aggregation would do the job:

```
var pipeline = aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$instances"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$name",
                "year": {
                    "$year": "$instances.date"
                },
                "month": {
                    "$month": "$instances.date"
                },
                "day": {
                    "$dayOfYear": "$instances.date"
                }
            },
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            },
            "data": {
                "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "count": {
                "$gt": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$data"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$data.name",
                "_id": "$data._id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$_id._id",
            "name": "$_id.name"
        }
    }
]);
db.test.aggregate(pipeline);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55506d0a180e849972939056"),
            "name" : "name1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55506d0a180e849972939058"),
            "name" : "name1"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The above aggregation pipeline has an [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operation as the first step which deconstructs the `instances` array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value.

The next pipeline stage [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) groups the documents by the `"name"`, `"instances.date"` fields (the date field is split into three fields by using the **[Date Aggregation Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators)**), calculates the `count` field for each group, and outputs a document for each unique `name` and `date` (down to the day part). There is an extra array field in the group `data`, which uses the system variable [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) to store the original root document, i.e. the top-level document, currently being processed in the aggregation pipeline stage. This root document is added to the array by using the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) array operator.

Further down the pipeline you will then need to filter those documents which are duplicates when grouped by name and date through the use of a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline with the specified criteria that the count should be greater than one.

Another [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operation is then applied on the `data` field to extract the actual `_id` and `name` of the duplicates which would be grouped again to further streamline your documents.

An additional [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) pipeline stage would be necessary to shape your final documents structure by modifying the fields.

Use the aggregation result cursor to then iterate over the results using the [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) method and remove the other duplicate documents:

```
var cur = db.test.aggregate(pipeline);
cur.forEach(function (doc){
    var count = 0;
    if (count != 0){
        db.test.remove({"_id": doc._id});
    }
    count++;
});
```

Another option is to include an [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) operator as a final pipeline stage that writes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline to a specified collection that you can then query on and do the deletions:

```
var cur = db.outputcollection.find();
cur.forEach(function (doc){
    var count = 0;
    if (count != 0){
        db.test.remove({"_id": doc._id});
    }
    count++;
});
```

Comment: Kudos for mentioning `$addToSet`: I simply missed that part. But why not simply using `"$addToSet": "$_id"` ? Is there something obvious I missed there too ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux That's a great suggestion though I won't be tempted to include just the `$_id` field yet in the event that the OP may need other fields as well further down the pipeline, but yeah for just getting the duplicates I do concur only the `_id` field suffices. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it well you should [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and then [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by date and instance, [filtering out](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) groups of only one document. Something like that (I don't have access to MongoDB right now -- beware of the typos):

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$instances"},
  {$group: { _id: { name:"$name", day:{$dayOfYear:"$date"}, year:{$year:"$date"}}, count: {$sum: 1} }},
  {$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
])
```